# Is there any way to directly save serial port incoming data into file?

Tags: c#, serial-port, arrays, bytebuffer

I need to save whole incoming serial port data into a file. Some people suggest to use `File.WriteAllBytes` but it takes the all empty indexes of created byte array.

```
        Array.Resize(ref Read_Data2, Read_Data2.Length + incoming.Length);

        public void SaveData(byte[] incoming)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < incoming.Length; i++)
            {
                Read_Data2[x] = incoming[i];
                ++x;
            }


            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Test3.text", Read_Data2);
        }
```

I use that method to save all incoming bytes into Read_Data2 but i think something is wrong. It saves the empty indexes of byte array as i said before. How can i improve this or is there any better way to save the incoming serial port data into file?

Comment: It is a simple convenience method, it stops being convenient when your array doesn't have the right size.  Just like an array stops being convenient when you constantly have to resize it.  So either use `List<byte>` or use FileStream.

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void mySerialPort_DataReceived(System.Object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)

{

                SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
                byte[] bytesToRec = new byte[spL.byteToRead];
                Int64 bytes = spL.Read(bytesToRec, 0, bytesToRec.Length);
                navSerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                navSerialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                string filepath = @"" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + "KMTU_" +DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM-d-yyyy") + ".hex";
                FileStream LogFile = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create);
                LogFile.Write(bytesToRec, 0, bytesToRec.Length);
                 LogFile.Close();
}
```